# In InnoDB,is all sql in the transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I seems　have a wrong idea that :

```
update table_name set id=222 where id >333;
```

my old opinion is above single sql without `begin` and `commit` will not start a transaction.
but it seems wrong.

---

But when i read the mysql [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html),i found that seems that all sql will in a transaction.if you do not explicit use `begin` and `commit`,it will start transaction implicit in InnoDB.

> In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction. If autocommit mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own. By default, MySQL starts the session for each new connection with autocommit enabled, so MySQL does a commit after each SQL statement if that statement did not return an error. If a statement returns an error, the commit or rollback behavior depends on the error. See Section 14.21.4, “InnoDB Error Handling”.

### my question :

Is all sql will ececute in the transaction ,no matter whether do you use `begin` and `commit` explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it will be executed in **single** transactions - unless grouping statements with `START TRANSACTION` & `COMMIT` (the `autocommit` configuration will then be ignored, no matter it's value). `SET autocommit = 0/1` can be used to control the level of isolation on-the-fly. there's also a configuration option for that, in order to change the behavior globally:

```
[mysqld]
autocommit=0
```

the documentation for "Server System Variables" explains it in detail:

> The `autocommit` mode. If set to `1`, all changes to a table take effect immediately. If set to `0`, you must use `COMMIT` to accept a transaction or `ROLLBACK` to cancel it. If `autocommit` is `0` and you change it to `1`, MySQL performs an automatic `COMMIT` of any open transaction. Another way to begin a transaction is to use a `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN` statement.

Comment: in innodb，sql must in a transaction.may  in a implicit transaction or explicit transaction.no matter how,it must in a transaction. do it right?

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur in general, it will always be a transaction, the only difference in between `0` and `1` is, that it's single statement vs. the option to group several statements. there is no "right" or "wrong", because this barely depends on the statements issued - and if grouping statements makes sense. the only thing really wrong is `autocommit=0` and then forgetting to issue the `COMMIT`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Even if only `SELECT` statements are there in `autocommit=0` connection, should I issue `COMMIT`?